# Strong Induction, assuming k<n where k and n are not numbers

Tags: proof-writing, induction, computer-science

In strong Induction for the induction hypothesis you assume for all K, p(k) for k

If for example I am working with trees and not natural numbers can I still use this style of proof?

For example if I want my induction hypothesis to be that p(k) for k < n where n is a node in the tree and everything smaller than/bellow it (The nodes children,k) is assumed to be true.

In the proof would I have to define what the < operator does for two nodes?

Comment: Yes you can. The process is often called [structural induction.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, strong induction will work on a partially ordered set such as a tree, as long as  there are no infinite downward chains 
$a_1 > a_2 > a_3 > \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. As  André Nicolas says, this is called *structural induction*, and it applies to data types that are inductively defined, that is, the structure, or rather, the *construction* of their elements is given (a) by some *base cases*, and (b) by some *step cases* involving already given elements.

*Binary trees* for example are given (a) by one base case, the tree consisting of one *leaf node* (no children), and (b) one step case declaring that if you have already constructed two binary trees then you can join their roots to a common *root node* (parent node) and obtain a new binary tree.

In order to show that every binary tree has some property using induction, you would have to follow the construction cases: (a) show that the one-node tree has the property; (b) assume that two already constructed trees have the property (this would be the *induction hypothesis*), and show that the new tree that you get by joining them via a common root node must also have the property. You can also do the "strong" (also called *course-of-values*) version (b'): assume that the two already constructed trees, *as well as their own subtrees* have the property, and then show that the new tree must also have it.

A conceptual subtlety here is that you perform the induction not on *the nodes* of the tree, but on the different possible ways these can be pieced together to form the tree (that is to say: on *the structure* of the tree); the different types of nodes, namely leaf nodes and root nodes, are just your induction pivots. To this point, notice that structural induction generalizes the usual induction on natural numbers: just think of the data type of unary trees labelled by the characters $0$, $S$, and defined by (a) $0$ is a unary tree, and (b) if $m$ is an already constructed unary tree, then $Sm$ is also a unary tree. Here, the zero symbol $0$ plays the role of the one-node base case, and the successor symbol $S$ the (joining) root node of the step case. Indeed, when we perform the usual induction we induct not on nodes (which could only mean node labels) $0$ and $S$, but on numbers $0$, $1$, $2$, ..., that is on "unary trees" $0$, $S0$, $SS0$, ..., where $0$ for zero and $S$ for the successor $+1$ serve as the induction pivots.

> In the proof would I have to define what the < operator does for two nodes?

Well, the symbol "<" in this case would refer to the subtree relation, right?: $t<s$ would mean $t$ is a (proper) subtree of $s$. This has to be defined before you prove anything using it — in this case, you would want to use it if you performed strong induction. Note that definitions in inductively defined data types are wont to be *recursive*, to follow the inductive pattern as well: (a) define what the subtrees of the one-node tree are; (b) given the subtrees of two already constructed trees, define what the subtrees of the new tree are.

Answer (score 0):

Induction, and strong induction, are used to prove statements that are indexed by the natural  numbers $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  $k$ and $n$ need to be natural numbers, with a minimum value ($0$ or $1$ are the usual choices).  The *statements* need not be natural numbers, for example, the first statement $p(1)$ could be that "node number 1 satisfies property x" and the second statement $p(2)$ could be that "nodes number 1 and 2 satisfy property x" etc.